# Wiring in a Dusk/Dawn sensor to my porch light

Tags: wiring, light-fixture

I am trying to wire a Dusk/Dawn sensor into my covered porch light.  My problem is the sensor has Black, Red, White wire and my light has Black, White and Ground wires.  Which wires connect?

Comment: In addition to tester101's exact answer to your question, another consideration that must be considered is where the sensor is mounted.  Photocells mounted so that they see too much light from the fixture that they turn on will cycle.  It gets dark, so the light turns on-- but if the sensor is in that same zone it sees light now and thinks it should turn off, so it does... It's now in darkness and thinks it's time to turn on... Rinse and repeat until dawn.

Comment: Your sensor doesn't need a ground.  @Tyson Many modern photo sensors can "learn" what day and night look like, and in doing so, they factor for ambient light, spill light etc.  However they take a couple of days to learn.

Comment: @Harper I added the note because it's a fairly common mistake homeowners make adding photocells.  I answer the phone and write up service calls part of the day, when the customer starts, "we put a photocell on the front light..." I can almost finish there sentence with "and it goes on and off all night long."

Answer (score 4):

On the sensor black should be LINE, the ungrounded (hot) feed.  Red should be LOAD, the supply to the light. White should be neutral, and green is ground.

The black wire coming into the box, should be the ungrounded  (hot) feed (likely from a switch).  The white wire should be neutral, and green/bare is ground.

1. Connect all the grounds together, and to the box if it's metal.
2. Connect the white coming into the box, to the white from the light and sensor.
3. Connect the black coming into the box, to the black on the sensor.
4. Connect the red from the sensor, to the black from the light.